Imbalanced Diabetic Retinopathy Segmentation: Overfitting and Loss Function Choice
I'm training a U-net model for segmenting microaneurysms in diabetic retinopathy images. The dataset is imbalanced, with the background class (healthy tissue) dominating at around 96% and the foreground class (microaneurysms) representing only 4%.
I'm encountering two main issues:
Overfitting: The model seems to be overfitting the training data. The training loss decreases significantly, but the validation loss plateaus or even increases.
Negative Loss Function: While using binary cross-entropy (BCE) loss, I'm observing negative loss values during training.
Current Approach:
Model: U-net with EfficientNetB0 backbone and pre-trained weights from ImageNet.
Data Augmentation: Rotations and flips are applied for data augmentation.
Loss Function: Binary cross-entropy (BCE) is currently used.
expected the model to:
Learn relevant features from the training data.
Generalize well to unseen data (validation set), with both training and validation loss decreasing steadily throughout training.
Achieve a stable BCE loss that reflects the model's performance in differentiating foreground (microaneurysms) from background (healthy tissue)

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aaryapatel98/indian-diabetic-retinopathy-image-dataset
Here is dataset link

Are your target labels in the range [0, 1]?

Yes I had normalize it to make each pixel a 0 or 1
